# Scala / Cats: How to unzip an NonEmptyList

Tags: scala, scala-cats

The standard library offers the `unzip` method on `List`:

```scala
scala>val l = List((1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three"), (4, "four"), (5, "five"))

scala> l.unzip
// res13: (List[Int], List[String]) = (
//  List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
//  List("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
//)
```

Is there a way to achieve the same on `NonEmptyList` from the `cats` library:

```scala
scala> import cats.data.NonEmptyList

scala> val nel = NonEmptyList.of((1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three"), (4, "four"), (5, "five"))
//res15: NonEmptyList[(Int, String)] = NonEmptyList(
//  (1, "one"),
//  List((2, "two"), (3, "three"), (4, "four"), (5, "five"))
//)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do it all in one traversal, and often you don't even want to use one of the parts. I would write it like:

```
(nel.map(_._1), nel.map(_._2))
```

This avoids the awkward conversion away from an NEL and back.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply call `nel.toList` and use the standard `l.unzip` and then `NonEmptyList.fromList(unziped_list)` on the result.

**Edit**: As @Dylan said, you could also use `.fromListUnsafe` to get rid of the option.

Comment: +1 but I'd recommend using `.fromListUnsafe` at the end, since `.fromList` gets you an option, and since your result list is guaranteed to have come from a non-empty List, the "unsafe" method is safe to use.

Comment: @Dylan: Calling `.fromListUnsafe` is used instead of just calling `.get` on the resulting option?

Comment: @Ellesedil basically yes. [See for yourself](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/NonEmptyList.scala#L458)

Answer (score 2):

The `unzip` method is available for `NonEmptyList` if you import `cats.syntax.functor._`.

```
scala> import cats.data.NonEmptyList
                                                                             
scala> import cats.syntax.functor._
                                                                             
scala> val nel = NonEmptyList.of((1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three"), (4, "four"))
val nel: cats.data.NonEmptyList[(Int, String)] = NonEmptyList((1,one), (2,two), (3,three), (4,four))
                                                                             
scala> nel.unzip
val res0: (cats.data.NonEmptyList[Int], cats.data.NonEmptyList[String]) = (NonEmptyList(1, 2, 3, 4),NonEmptyList(one, two, three, four))
```